# How to bind SSL certificate having crt file

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm installing SSL certificate in my website and I tried following steps but still not website not working in https and still working on http

I already bind my crt file in below

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/http
    ServerName my_domain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/coolexample.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privatekey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

After type this command `apache2ctl configtest`
it shows Syntax OK

But after type last command `apache2ctl restart`
It shows following error message

> httpd not running, trying to start
>
> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>
> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>
> no listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> AH00015: Unable to open logs
>
> Action 'restart' failed.
>
> The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: If you do HTTPS you should bind on port 443 and not port 80. Did you apply the wisdom of the error message: The Apache error log may have more information. ?

Answer (score 0):

To activate SSL encryption you need an extra VirtualHost for port 443. This is often done within `Apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` which is platform dependend.

Within such a file you need an entry like (Windows example):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "C:/webserver/html/my_html"
  ServerName www.example.com
  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:!DSS
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCompression off
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/ProgramData/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/portal.digipen.de-crt.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/ProgramData/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/portal.digipen.de-key.pem"
  SSLCACertificateFile "C:/ProgramData/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/ca-portal.digipen.de-crt.pem"

  <IfModule headers_module>
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  Header always set x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN"
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  </IfModule>

  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  SSLProxyEngine on

  EnableSendfile off
  EnableMMAP off 
</VirtualHost>
```